# Routing incoming requests to deployments using same host but diffent target ports (example with wordpress and phpmyadmin)

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I want to host a wordpress site using a number of services (wordpress, mysql, phpmyadmin, backend-service) for full functionality. I already have built those services using docker-compose and now I want to host them using kubernetes running on google (gke). On the SAME HOST I want to reach the wordpress service and the phpmyadmin service using different PORTS in the request. This seems logical to me, since I do not want to have a second external IP just for the phpmyadmin service.

Using docker-compose, this was easy. All external requests on port 80 for wordpress and all requests on port 8080 for phpmyadmin:

```
    services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes: 
      - ./database/:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress-wpd
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./xdebug
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./Wordpress/:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 1
    networks:
      wpsite:
      mail:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./Backend/
    ports:
      - '5555:5555' #prod
      - '6666:6666' #add debug
      - '80:80' #apache debug
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./backend/:/var/www/backend/
    networks:
      wpsite:
networks:
  wpsite:
  mail:
```

Now using kubernetes this seems to be harder. With ingress, I can only allocate traffic from port 80 based on path, not port. I thought of using a load balancer to allocate traffic to my wordpress and phpmyadmin.

loadbalancer.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: wordpress
    #target: wordpress-deployment
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: phpmyadmin
    #target: phpmyadmin-deployment
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
```

phpmyadmin.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-deployment
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: phpmyadmin
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: PMA_HOST
              value: mysql-service
            - name: PMA_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

wordpress.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-deployment
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: home-wordpress 
        image: eu.gcr.io/myproject/home_wordpress:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/www/html
            name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        env:
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
              value: mysql-service
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: MYSQL_USER
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress-pv-claim
```

Problem:
Since both containers (wordpress and phpmyadmin) are using the same port 80 at the end, it seems to me that the frontend-service is forwarding traffic from port 80 and from port 8080 to them both. I sometimes see the wordpress container replying to a request and sometimes the phpmyadmin container to the same (host/port) request.

**Question:**
Can this be solved using additional NodePort-services?

*So for wordpress:*
LoadBalancer service 80:80 --> (additional) NodePort wordpress service 80:80 --> wordpress deployment (80)

*For phpmyadmin:*
LoadBalancer service 8080:8080 --> (additional) NodePort phpmyadmin service 8080:80 --> phpmyadmin deployment (80)

In doing so I would need to use different labels/selectors for the loadbalancer and the deployments so the phpmyadmin deployment will not receive the port 80 wordpress requests from the loadbalancer directly.

I did not understand the kubernetes documentation on labels and selectors very well and it is confusing that there are various possibilities to position these in a yaml file (under spec? Under metadata? On what basis to choose key? On what basis to choose value?).

Or is there a simpler solution to all this? Overall it seems much more complicated than the docker-compose example...

Comment: Update: It seems that the loadbalancer-service cannot direct traffic to a nodeport-service. In gke it just shows that there are no pods connected to the loadbalancer and it does not see the nodeport-services..

Comment: Do you have to use different ports?  Or are you ok load balancing externally based on host path?

Comment: I think that using different ports is way easier than using different host paths. I have my applications nicely separated using ports.